# Angular 2 : Setting Angular code VS 2015 update 4 version not working

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to setup VS 2015 Update 3 version to make code worked. Initially project worked when I used 'NPM start' command. Later I made changes to make code worked. I made the following change to the system.config.ts file:-

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '***/***node_modules/'
},
```

After that I can getting the following error:-

app/main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

As per one of the blog post, I made change to the following:-

```
<script>
  System.import('***app/***main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think error in your node module path that given in system.config

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the issue and solution is as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/src/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="*../*node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="*../*node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="*../*node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('*../src/*main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Refer the changes above. App is working fine.

thanks